# NiFi API on remote host SocketException

Tags: java, api, ssl-certificate, apache-nifi

When I run NiFI 1.8 on my local machine (http://localhost:8080/nifi) I am able to interact with the application through the API using Java. I can start and stop processors, and I get a 200 response code everytime.

When I use the same code to interact with a remote NiFI instance (which uses authentication) I get a SocketException, with the message "Unexpected end of file from server"

I tried setting credentials of the HttpURLConnection but it made no difference. Is this an issue with a certificate? If it is I'm not sure how to obtain and set the correct one.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to authenticate against NiFi. All secure instances can accept client certificates by default, so if you have a *user* entity configured for some identity `nifi_client`, you can issue a certificate with that `CN` and use it when invoking the API from your Java client. Generally this involves putting the key and certificate in a Java Keystore (`*.jks`) and having a truststore that contains the public certificate of the NiFi server. There are specific instructions for handling certificate authentication in the [NiFi Admin Guide](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html), and you can look at the [NiFi CLI](https://github.com/apache/nifi/tree/master/nifi-toolkit/nifi-toolkit-cli#security-configuration) as an example of an authenticated client.